# Return from Kafka consumer when there is no message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka

I want to process a topic in application startup using [Confluent dotnet client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/). Assume following example:

```
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var cr = c.Consume();
            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
        }
        catch (ConsumeException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
        }
    }
```

When there is no new message in Kafka, c.Consume will be blocked. Because I want to use it for application startup (Like cache warm up) I want to proceed my code when I found there is no new message.

I know there is an overload for setting timeout like `c.Consume(timeout)` but the problem with this approach is that if you have a message in your topic and the time duration of reading the message was more than your timeout, You receive null output which is not desirable.

Comment: So what is your desirable approach to stop consuming?

Comment: Is there a method that indicate we are in the end of partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer(s) is not supposed to be aware of the producer(s).

Now if you want to know that you have read everything in the topic from the moment you start to consume, you can:

1. Load the newest offset before starting to consume.
2. Then start consuming messages.
3. If the message's offset is the same as the newest offset you loaded before, stop consuming.

I'm not a `C#` developper but from what I read in the dotnet confluent doc you can call `QueryWatermarkOffsets`on the consumer to get oldest and newest offset. https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Consumer.html#Confluent_Kafka_Consumer_QueryWatermarkOffsets_Confluent_Kafka_TopicPartition_

And then, on the `Message`class you have an `Offset` accessor. So the whole thing should not be too hard to achieve. 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Message.html#Confluent_Kafka_Message_Offset

Comment: Thank you. This gives me the end offset and works fine! Could you add `QueryWatermarkOffsets` method to your answer? I receive the watermark by the following query:

var watermark = c.QueryWatermarkOffsets(new TopicPartition("mytopic", new Partition(0)), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer to mention `QueryWatermarkOffsets`instead of `GetWatermarkOffsets`. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OnPartitionEOF` event that indicates you have reached the end of partition.

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
bool isContinue = true;

c.OnPartitionEOF += (o, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You have reached end of partition");
        isContinue = false;
        source.Cancel();
    };    
while (isContinue)
{
    try
    {
        var cr = c.Consume(source.Token);
        Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
    }
    catch (ConsumeException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But `OnPartitionEOF` has removed as described in https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Your welcome. So you can detect end of partition by checking `cr.IsPartitionEOF` after consuming.

Comment: `IsPartitionEOF` should work, but I don't know why it returns always false (I just created a topic with a single message). Also, I must wait for first Consume call (That might be blocked) to check `IsPartitionEOF`. Maybe stable release solves the problem.

Comment: I didn't work because I did not enable it in config:  var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                EnablePartitionEof = true
            };

Could you change your answer to reflect IsPartitionEOF feature so other users can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Consumer.IsPartitionEOF useful.

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.